# Clarification on the usage of でも in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

縁起でもないこと言わないでよ

I understand the gist of the sentence. The speaker is saying something like "Please don't say something so grim". But how does でも play into this? Why is it not 縁起ないこと instead? So it would be like "thing with no luck".

The closest definition which makes sense to me is "~or something" for でも. But, even if don't make sense because there is a lack of commas after でも

Comment: Probably needs context to answer this.

Comment: @Ben The other party said something ominous. And the friend is replying, which is this sentence.

Comment: I looked this word up in the dictionary, and it seems to be a set phrase: https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%B1%EF%B5%AF%A4%C7%A4%E2%A4%CA%A4%A4

Comment: ＠Ben Thank you, no wonder it does not make sense to me when i broke it up into components.

Comment: I was going to post an answer but I actually don't understand why it is でもない in the set phrase rather than ではない or something. All the online dictionaries just say "よい前兆でもないから" or とんでもない or something like that, but why it's でも I don't know, since that usually means more like "not even".